# Hide ellipses if there is not even single character with it

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a button with icon and some text.Currently i am showing ellipses on text-overflow. But i want to show only icon and not the ellipses, if only ellipses are displayed.

Like in the example shown below, since there is not even a single character with ellipses, and only three dots (...) are displayed. I want to hide to hide those three dots and display only button with icon.

```css
.btn{
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 46px;
  text-overflow: ellipses;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.btn .icon{
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.btn .text{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="btn">
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-html5"></i></span>
        <span class="text">button</span>
    </button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: On Firefox I see `bu` (with the "u" cut) intead of `...`. I think the best way is to check the dimensions with JS to see it it fits, I (personnally) know no way to do this in CSS only

Comment: This is not reproducible on firefox.

Comment: I don`t want to hide the text, i am ok with text with ellipses. For example, even is text is like " b..." it is acceptable. I only want to hide ellipses, when it not even contains a single character of text, that it when it is displayed as "..." only.

Comment: While I'm surprised there's no way I know of to do this with CSS, I wouldn't expect this specific case of overflow to have a special behavior either. The ellipses have a semantically important role in indicating that text is being hidden, regardless of whether any portion of overflowing text is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this entirely works for what you are looking for, but seems to at first look.

```css
.btn{
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
}
.btn .icon{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}

.btn .text{
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 30px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button class="btn">
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-html5"></i><span class="text">testing</span></span>
        
    </button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure it works at all, in here the icon and the text are outside of the button, which has 6px height..